# Calculate balance wages

Tags: c#, object-oriented, mvp

In the following code I'm trying to calculate Net Wage of employees and classes `Earning`, `Deduction` and `WageBalance` has a composition relationship with `WageInfo`. And there is a class called `WageManager` which is having a association with `WageInfo`, handling all operations like `BalanceWage()`. DataService class encapsulates all db logic.  Please review my code and let me know of any flaws.

Is the way I've implemented the relationships correct?  Would you have a method to calculate `BalanceWage` in a more elegant way?

[image]

```
    class WageManager
    {
        WageInfo _WageInfo;
        DataService _DataService;


        public WageManager(WageInfo wageInfo, DataService dataService )
        {
            _WageInfo = wageInfo;
            _DataService = dataService;
        }


        public List<WageBalance> BalanceWages()
        {

            var earningList = _DataService.GetEarningsList(); //DataService returns a List<Earning> list
            var deductionList = _DataService.GetDeductionList(); //DataService returns a List<Deduction>
            int i = 0;

            foreach (Earning e in earningList)
            {

    // Sum all earnings...

            var totalEarnings = earningList[i].AmountForEPF + earningList[i].OverTimeAmount + earningList[i].IncentiveAllowance + earningList[i].SpecialAllowance + earningList[i].OtherAllowance + earningList[i].ExtraShiftAmount + earningList[i].BroughtForwardAmount;

    // Sum all deductions...

            var totalDeductions = deductionList[i].AdvanceAmount + deductionList[i].CarriedForwardAmount + deductionList[i].DeathDonationAmount + deductionList[i].EPFAmount + deductionList[i].FineAmount + deductionList[i].InsuranceInstalmentAmount + deductionList[i].LoanInstalmentAmount + deductionList[i].MealsAmount + deductionList[i].OtherDeductionAmount + deductionList[i].UniformInstalmentAmount + deductionList[i].WelfareAmount;
            var employeeID = earningList[i].EmployeeID;
            var netEarning = totalEarnings - totalDeductions;

            WageInfo wageInfo = new WageInfo();

            wageInfo.WageBalance.EmployeeID = employeeID;
            wageInfo.WageBalance.NetWage = decimal.Truncate(netEarning / 100) * 100;
            wageInfo.WageBalance.CarriedForwardAmount = netEarning - wageInfo.WageBalance.NetWage;

            _WageInfo.WageBalanceList.Add(wageInfo.WageBalance);
            i += 1;
        }

        _DataService.BalanceWages(_WageInfo.WageBalanceList);

        return _WageInfo.WageBalanceList;
    }
}


class WageInfo
{
    public DateTime WagePeriodStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime WagePeriodEndDate { get; set; } 
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public Deduction Deduction = new Deduction();
    public Earning Earning = new Earning();
    public WageBalance WageBalance = new WageBalance();
    public List<WageBalance> WageBalanceList = new List<WageBalance>();

    public WageInfo()
    {
    }

}

public class WageBalance
{
    public int EmployeeID {get;set;}
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public decimal NetWage { get; set; }
    public decimal CarriedForwardAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does `Deduction` have `employeeID` also? And how do you know `GetEarningsList()` and `GetDeductionList()` return matching elements? How do you know they will stay that way?

Comment: @abuzittin gillifirca, Yes both Deduction and Earning have employeeID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have a pair of lists which you iterate through based on the elements contained in the `earningList`. This is potentially dangerous without validation. When the `earningList` is longer than `deductionList`, you will run into an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

```
var earningList = _DataService.GetEarningsList(); //DataService returns a List<Earning> list
var deductionList = _DataService.GetDeductionList(); //DataService returns a List<Deduction>

int i = 0;
foreach (Earning e in earningList)
{
    //...
    i += 1;
}
```

So in order to prevent that to happen, detect it in advance and handle it.

```
if (earningList.Count != deductionList.Count)
{
    //handle exception...
}
```

Since you dealing with two identical list, you can zip them together with [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and loop through both at same time

```
var pairedList = earningList.Zip(deductionList, (e,d) => new { Earning = e, Deduction = d });
foreach(var pair in pairedList)
{
    //calculate wage with pair.Earning and pair.Deduction...
}
```

> If I zip two list as above, is it possible to show these two lists in two DataGridViews?

Assume that we lost the reference to earningList and deductionList somehow and that you want to extract the original lists back from the `pairedList` to display each separately on `DataGridView`, it can be done with `IEnumerable.Select` :

```
//As dgv's DataSource doesn't take IEnumerable as valid source,
//we need to convert it to one of the interface it accepts : IList
dgvEarning.DataSource = pairedList.Select(p => p.Earning).ToList();
dgvDeduction.DataSource = pairedList.Select(p => p.Deduction).ToList();
```

Comment: If I zip two list as above, is it possible to show these two lists in two DataGridViews?

Comment: I've updated my answer for your question.

Comment: Could we link more than two lists in this way? I would like getting a WageInfo object returned from DataService rather than getting Earning, decuction etc. as these are composite objects. But the problem is how to access those private fields of WageInfo? [private List<Earning>;]

Comment: @Chathuranga You can expand the existing list by zipping it against the list of `WageInfo` : `pairedList.Zip(anotherList, (p,a) => new { p.Earning, p.Deduction, Something = a });`

Comment: However, if you have more than just that, use a `Select` to clue them clue together : `Enumerable.Range(0, firstList.Count).Select(i => new { First = firstList[i]; Second = secondList[i]; LastA = lastList[i].PropertyA });

Comment: You can only access `private` fields/properties/methods within the declaring class; It is the definition of [private][http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx] modifier

Answer (score 13):

### Formatting

formatting inside your `foreach` should be indented

This:

```
        foreach (Earning e in earningList)
        {

// Sum all earnings...

        var totalEarnings = earningList[i].AmountForEPF + earningList[i].OverTimeAmount + earningList[i].IncentiveAllowance + earningList[i].SpecialAllowance + earningList[i].OtherAllowance + earningList[i].ExtraShiftAmount + earningList[i].BroughtForwardAmount;
```

Should look like this

```
        foreach (Earning e in earningList)
        {
            // Sum all earnings...
            var totalEarnings = earningList[i].AmountForEPF + earningList[i].OverTimeAmount + earningList[i].IncentiveAllowance + earningList[i].SpecialAllowance + earningList[i].OtherAllowance + earningList[i].ExtraShiftAmount + earningList[i].BroughtForwardAmount;
            ...
        }
```

---

When you are adding things together (either in concatenation or variable addition) you can multi-line the expression because C# is awesome and isn't `NewLine` Terminated, so this:

```
  var totalDeductions = deductionList[i].AdvanceAmount + deductionList[i].CarriedForwardAmount + deductionList[i].DeathDonationAmount + deductionList[i].EPFAmount + deductionList[i].FineAmount + deductionList[i].InsuranceInstalmentAmount + deductionList[i].LoanInstalmentAmount + deductionList[i].MealsAmount + deductionList[i].OtherDeductionAmount + deductionList[i].UniformInstalmentAmount + deductionList[i].WelfareAmount;
```

can be easier read when written like this:

```
  var totalDeductions = deductionList[i].AdvanceAmount +
      deductionList[i].CarriedForwardAmount + 
      deductionList[i].DeathDonationAmount + 
      deductionList[i].EPFAmount + 
      deductionList[i].FineAmount + 
      deductionList[i].InsuranceInstalmentAmount + 
      deductionList[i].LoanInstalmentAmount + 
      deductionList[i].MealsAmount + 
      deductionList[i].OtherDeductionAmount + 
      deductionList[i].UniformInstalmentAmount + 
      deductionList[i].WelfareAmount;
```

I am looking into making this easier to do as well,  that just looks messy

---

### Organization

The more that I look at your code, there are more things that I would change.

your `Deduction` and `Earning` objects are created and maintained by your `WageInfo` class  so really you should be using a `wageInfoList`  and each item in that list will have one `Deduction` object and one `Earning` object

This means that the `WageInfo` object should have all the information to hand off to the `WageManager`.  The `WageManager` shouldn't directly see the `Deduction` or `Earning` objects that live in the `WageInfo` Object that is called by the `WageManager`.

Comment: As for the readability with adding array elements, I think it would read better if the operator was placed in front.

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me that you're hard-coding *far* too much here.

IMO, this type of task should be heavily database driven. For example, each item of earning and each deduction should have an amount, and a category. The category should come from a table in the database. So, you'd end up with one table of categories of deductions including the ones you have above (welfare, insurance, EPF, fine, meals, etc.) That table would probably have its permissions set so most normal users could only select from among the existing categories, but someone with administrative rights could add new ones. Of course, earnings would be pretty much the same way.

The code would then query the database for all deductions that apply to a particular employee during a specified time period, and add them together to get that employee's deductions for a pay period, total for the year, or whatever. This lets you (among other things) add or remove deductions without modifying the code.

The simple fact is that it's vain to even *hope* that when you write the code you've thought of every possible category of deduction somebody might want or need. Hard-coding leaves only two real choices: either resign yourself to modifying the code constantly forever, or force users to twist and stretch everything that arises to fit the categories that are currently available. In practice, such systems typically end up with some ugly combination of both.

Moving the categories to a database probably won't eliminate that--if somebody needs an administrator to add a category means somebody will inevitably find it more work than it's worth at least once in a while. Even if you let normal users add categories, some will still be too lazy to add a category sometimes<sup>1</sup>. Nonetheless, with a reasonable system it takes only fairly minimal work on the part of a few people to keep the system working fairly smoothly, at least as a rule.

---

<sub>1. For comparison, I'd cite the tags system on this site (and most others like it). Yes, moderators need to edit tags on questions semi-regularly (hi @Jamal) -- but at least being an entry in a database table means they have the tools available to do that editing, without having to ask somebody at Stack Exchange to re-compile the code every time they need a new tag.</sub>

Comment: I understand the importance of a category table. But I don't understand whats in my code far too much hard coding. All deductions and earnings are calculate by some other algorithm and saved in a table. Then those figures are accessed by methods like _DataService.GetEarningsList() in the above code.

Comment: I was referring to things like `AmountForEPF`, `OverTimeAmount`, `IncentiveAllowance`, `SpecialAllowance`, and so on.